# Assigning a function to a variable in Python

Tags: python, function, variable-assignment

I have a function and I have to use more than one. When I assign to only one variable, everthing is OK. But when I assign to second variable or other, I just get last assignment result. How can I fix this.
Example:

```
def set_cnum(rpart, ipart):
    set_cnum.rp = rpart
    set_cnum.ip = ipart

a=set_cnum
b=set_cnum
a(30,40)
b(12,8)


print a.rp,a.ip
```

output

```
12 8
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use a function like a class? This is not what functions are for.

Comment: I assume that's just an example, but FWIW, Python has a built-in `complex` type, so you don't need to create your own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of a function, use a class.

```
class setCnum:
    def __init__(self,rp, ip):
       self.rp = rp
       self.ip = ip

 a = setCnum(12, 8)
 print(a.rp) # Returns 12
 print(a.ip) # Returns 8
```

Comment: What's the purpose of those _class_ attributes `rb` and `ip`?

Comment: nothing. It's just a coding habit to initialize the values first.

Comment: @PM2Ring Judging by OPs question this should represent a complex number with a ***r***eal and ***i***maginary ***p***arts.

Comment: @DeepSpace I think he meant why add `rb = 0` and `ip = 0` at the beginning of the class.

Comment: @DeepSpace The _instance_ attributes `rp` and `ip` can do that. Those _class_ attributes aren't necessary.

Comment: That's not a great "coding habit."

Comment: removed my coding habit.

Comment: FWIW, the `rb` and `ip` defined before your `__init__` method are attributes of the class. They are distinct from instance attributes that you create in the `__init__` (or any other method). Class attributes can be useful (after all, the class's methods are also class attributes), but they should be used with care, since they're shared by all instances of the class.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Thanks a lot for clearing that up.